# Update text in TextView

Tags: android

In the beginning the `TextView` is empty and after that i do something i need to update the text in `TextView`.

**Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Test.test.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="@string/Title1"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fully Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView2 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ///do something...
            textView2.setText("dad");// instead "dad" i put string value.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not working.

Someone has idea?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: why arent you trying `textView1.setText("dad");`. Thats a completely different textview you are setting text of

Comment: I got confused, updated the question

Comment: upload your layout xml and activitly fully

Comment: You are doing something that is not shown above. Are you setting it from a thread of async task wrongly? We would need more code to determine the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, my first guess for not updating the textView2 text would be an exception generated somewhere inside **/// do something...** part of code you haven't posted. Have you checked for possible exceptions?

My second guess would be that other views are overlapping the textView2. You use constrained layout and your views are not properly constrained in which case they all tend to stick to upper left corner and overlap each other. Try to put some static text for your textView2 with android:text="some_text" , check your layout in Android Studio layout designer, and properly constrain each view both horizontally and vertically .

Comment: I check if i can set text to the another TextView(textView1 in code above) and it's work.
What can do problem in the layout xml on the textView2?

Comment: One idea - remove all views except textView2, so it can't be covered with another view in which case you should see it regardless of the missing constraints.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting text on wrong textView

```
textView1.setText("dad");
```

EDIT:
You have completly changed your post. Put your all code instead of

```
// do something
```